# Reading values from a text file to a linked list (no array of structs) to use for a stack; advice?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, stack

I have a question. I am trying to read integer values from a file into a linked list, which will then be used for push and pop functions. I've done my push and pop functions, but I am trying to figure out if I have done the reading correctly. With my code so far, I used fscanf to read the file and printed it and it's printing all values. When I do my push function, it's not printing that correctly. Any advice on what I may be doing wrong.

```
4
2
1
6
1
5
2
3
3
1
6
1
\\values to be read from file
```

code below:

```
//linked list with place to store values and nodes
struct stack_list {
    int list_values;
    struct stack_list *node;
};

struct stack_list *head_node = NULL; //empty list

void stack_print(struct stack_list *);  //prototype to print list
struct stack_list * push(struct stack_list * n, struct stack_list * c); //prototype to push values

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE * fp;  //opening file
    fp = fopen("filename", "r");  //gives name of file to open
    struct stack_list * mock = (struct stack_list *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack_list));
    //int values[12];  //array to be used to collect values to pass to my list
    //int n, t;

    if (fp == NULL){

        printf("File not provided.");
    }
    else if (fp != NULL) {

        printf("Printing values first: \n");

        while (fscanf(fp,"%d", &mock->list_values) == 1) {
            mock->node = head_node;
            printf("%d\n", mock->list_values);
        }
    }
    push(mock, constructor_stack(mock));
    stack_print(mock);
}

struct stack_list * constructor_stack(int j){
    struct stack_list * my_node = (struct stack_list *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack_list));
    my_node->list_values = j;
    my_node->node = NULL;
    return my_node;
}

struct stack_list * push(struct stack_list * num_list, struct stack_list * check_nodes) {

    printf("Added values to stack:\n");
    printf("Push: %d\n", check_nodes->list_values);
    check_nodes->list_values = num_list;
    return check_nodes;
}
```

This is part of what I have so far. I did attempt to use an array to just store the values and pass to my list, but that didn't work either.

```
int values[12];  //array to be used to collect values to pass to my list
int n, t;

while (fscanf(fp,"%d", &values[n]) == 1) {
            n++;
        }
    }
    for (t = 0; t < 12; ++t) { //iterating over array where values are stored
        head_node = values[t]; //inputting values into the empty list
        printf("%d\n", head_node); //printing values passed to empty list for reference
    }
```

This is the output that I receive.

```
Printing values first:
4
2
1
6
1
5
2
3
3
1
6
1
Added values to stack:
Push: 136352
Printing stack:
1111111111111111111111
```

This printed the values but did not work in my push function either. I appreciate any advice!

Comment: regarding: `int values[12];`  What if there are more than 12 values in the file?  Suggest: `while ( n < 12 && fscanf(fp,"%d", &values[n]) == 1) {`

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct stack_list * my_node = (struct stack_list *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack_list));`  1) the returned type, in C, is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: the posted code contains a 'magic' number.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 12.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `if (fp == NULL){

        printf("File not provided.");`  The check for NULL of `fp` should be immediately after the call to `fopen()`  and should be written as: `if( !fp ) { perror( "fopen failed" );`  usually followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  where `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the header file: `stdlib.h`  The call to `perror()` will output to `stderr`, both you error message and the reason the system thinks the function failed

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: regarding: `else if (fp != NULL) {`  Since the preceding `if()` checked for == NULL, there is no need to say anything other than `else`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Suggest: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: The posted code seems to be missing the call(s) to `free()` for all those allocated heap memory allocations (via `malloc()` ).  The result is a massive memory leak

Comment: regarding: `printf("Push: %d\n", check_nodes->list_values);
    check_nodes->list_values = num_list;`  the call to `printf()` will output trash.  then the assignment will overlay that trash with the actual input value.  However, even so, this is NOT creating a linked list

Comment: what does this function do?  `void stack_print(struct stack_list *);`   Since that function is not posted, how are we know that the source of your problem isn't in that functiom